# Printing CGI header twice behaving differently for different CGI and Apache version

Tags: apache, perl, cgi

I am running the below code in two different environments with below mentioned versions  and outputs:

Environment 1 (Perl : 5.14.1 , CGI module : 3.52, Apache : 2.4.12) outputs:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 Hello Everybody .. !
```

Environment 2 (Perl : 5.6.1 , CGI module : 2.752, Apache : 1.1) outputs:

```
Hello Everybody .. !
```

I have seen that the CGI header function has undergone some changes in 3.52 from 2.752. Can anybody please help me understand if the difference in output 
for printing the header twice is due to the CGI version or Apache version ?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
my $q = CGI->new;

print $q->header();
print $q->header();

print $q->start_html();

warn "This is test header issue script \n";
print "Hello Everybody .. !";
print $q->end_html();
```

Comment: Why are you printing the headers twice in the first place?

Comment: Well, I do not want to print it twice. This is just a small demonstration of my real-time code where in the earlier version (Env-1) the header is getting printed twice by mistake. I want to solve it. In order to do that I noticed this behaviour.

Comment: I assume you've copied the rendered output from your browser, since there's no HTML in it. Run your script on the command line and edit the output into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following will suppress duplicate headers in newer versions:

```
use CGI qw( -unique_headers );
```

If that causes an error in the older version, you can use the following instead:

```
{
   no warnings qw( once );
   $CGI::HEADERS_ONCE = 1;
}
```